# Android NDK crash when creating firebase instance

Tags: c++, firebase, android-ndk

I try to integrate firebase to my ndk project but its crash when during init firebase.
Here is the code.

```
#include "firebase/app.h"
void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{
    {
        using namespace firebase;
        auto env = state->activity->env;
        auto activity = state->activity->clazz;
        auto app = App::Create(env, activity);

    }
}
```

Here is the crash dump ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
> ********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.0/NYC/4409132:user/release-keys'
#00 0x0038e29b /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+75)
#01 0x0038f168 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_Pc+120)
#02 0x0013d112 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+82)
#03 0x0013c9ff /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+239)
#04 0x0013b4eb /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck22CheckPossibleHeapValueERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEcNS_12JniValueTypeE+91)
#05 0x0013a26e /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+1390)
#06 0x00127ed6 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+982)
#07 0x0007a676 /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (_ZN8firebase4util9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+38)
#08 0x000685f6 /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (_ZN8firebase4util15FindClassGlobalEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectPKNSt6__ndk16vectorINS_8internal12EmbeddedFileENS5_9allocatorIS8_EEEEPKcNS0_16ClassRequirementE+54)
#09 0x000728c5 /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (_ZN8firebase4util25InitializeActivityClassesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+117)
#10 0x00072f7a /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (_ZN8firebase4util10InitializeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+74)
#11 0x00063ace /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so
#12 0x0006463a /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (_ZN8firebase3App6CreateEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+58)
#13 0x000609fd /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so (android_main+77)
#14 0x0006261d /data/app/com.plane.pong-1/lib/x86/libmain.so
#15 0x00074fb2 /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
#16 0x0002026e /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
#17 0x0001e046 /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
Crash dump is completed
```

Comment: I can't see anything obvious there. You're probably crashing in InitializeActivityClasses somewhere: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/blob/1d13237b37dcecdc3a48ccd882337e03d4ac5bf0/app/src/util_android.cc#L418 . My guess is that maybe a native dependency is missing? See step 5 of my code lab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/get-started-with-firebase-cpp#4

Comment: Native meaning Java in this case . The FindClass and JNI signatures make this my suspected area of focus